# mysql query display instead of NULL - 0

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT
A.cod_material,
SUM(B.cantidad_pedido) as cantidad_pedido
FROM materiales AS A LEFT JOIN ingreso_material AS B 
on A.cod_material = B.cod_material GROUP BY A.cod_material;
```

My results are

```
cod_material    cantidad_pedido
--------------------------------
321010001             NULL
321010002             25125
321010004             1283
321010006             NULL
```

And I want it to show instead of NULL (0)

```
321010001               0
```

Ty for your help

Comment: Best way is to alter your table and give them a default value of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` here. The function returns the *first* non-`NULL` value.

```
SELECT
  A.cod_material,
  COALESCE(SUM(B.cantidad_pedido), 0) as cantidad_pedido
FROM materiales AS A LEFT JOIN ingreso_material AS B 
  on A.cod_material = B.cod_material GROUP BY A.cod_material;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case`

```
SUM(case when B.cantidad_pedido IS NULL 
         then 0 
         else B.cantidad_pedido 
    end) as cantidad_pedido
```

or `isnull`

```
SUM(ISNULL(B.cantidad_pedido, 0)) as cantidad_pedido
```